I made a web-crawler, but the output is garbled text
I am making web-crawler that pick up specific content and output.
However the output by crawler is somehow garbled text.
The code:
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

// Trying to crawl bbs posts
fetch('https://target-website.tld/bbs.cgi')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(htmlString => {
    const dom = new JSDOM(htmlString);
    // posts is inside of <pre> that is inside of <blockquote>
    const blockQuotes = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('blockquote');
    blockQuotes.forEach(blockQuote => {
      const preElements = blockQuote.querySelectorAll('pre');
      preElements.forEach(pre => {
        console.log(pre.textContent.trim());
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching HTML:', error));


Output example:
�Ôg�I�����āI낻��܂��....����(;�L�D`)

I have tried setting UTF-8 header on fetch, It doesn't work.
I want to output text without garbled.
P.S: 99% of posts are written in Japanese, so I thought using UTF-8 will fix this issues, I don't know how.
Example HTML
<blockquote>
<pre><font color="#d1d1d1">&gt; おはようございます。今日はいい天気ですね。</font>

そうですね。おはようございます。

<a href="#">参考：2024/11/25(月)11時43分33秒</a>
</pre>

</blockquote>


Is this on Windows?  Your console probably isn't set for UTF-8.  Try doing "chcp 65001" before you run your app.

It's hard to guess what that URL returns.

There's not enough debugging information in this question. What does console.log(htmlString) show you?

Hello, for the output of console.log(htmlString) provide me a html structures however the Japanese texts are garbled.
so I thought this is very similar to what happening when forgot <meta charset="utf-8"> web browser wont't render texts properly.
I am using Mac OS.
I'll add example HTML on the question later.

As a test, can you please just run this single-line node.js program:  console.log('もぐもぐぷりん'); and see if the output text is also "garbled"?  (If it is garbled, then your terminal is not configured correctly.  Try running from vscode integrated terminal.)

Yes console.log("もぐもぐぷりん"); works.
Also the example HTML added on question, I put that on my web-server  to try the program.
It worked on that page, which mean the bug happen only on the website where I am going to crawl.
If I have new information, I'll post.

Thanks everyone. However I self solved.
I just changed response.text() to response.buffer() and used 'iconv-lite to convert Shift_JIS to UTF-8.

You shouldn't be posting your solution in your question (I rolled all that back). Good to see you posting it an answer (where it needs to be).

The issues was happening because of the encode method of the website you are trying to crawl.
You can use jschardet to detect encoding method and iconv-lite to conver to UTF-8.
Heres how:
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

// import these
import pkg from 'iconv-lite';
import jschardet from 'jschardet';

function convertToUtf8(buffer) {
    const detected = jschardet.detect(buffer);
    const encoding = detected.encoding;

    if (encoding === 'UTF-8' || encoding === 'ASCII') return buffer.toString('utf8'); 


    try {
        const decodedString = pkg.decode(buffer, encoding);
        return decodedString;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error decoding with encoding', encoding, error);
        return null;
    }
} 

fetch('https://target-website.tld/bbs.cgi')
  .then(response => response.buffer()) // get the buffer instead getting text.
  .then(buffer => {
    // convert to utf-8
    var htmlString = convertToUtf8(buffer);
    console.log(htmlString); // it works.

    // some code
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching HTML:', error));

